# How to remove models that are no longer bound to dom

Tags: javascript, html, dom, angularjs

I have a form that has a bunch of logic about which elements to show using ng-if. For example I might have a country drop down and if USA is selected it will show the state drop down which was conditioned upon an ng-if for country. Perhaps this was not the best way to do it so if there are recommendations for a different approach for the next project that will be appreciated but I need to finish this project with few major modifications.

The problem is if a user selects a country say USA and then a state, and then selects a different country. The state is still selected within the model. So how would I go about removing the state field. There are deeply nested ng-if's (think about 4-5 levels).

#### Example

```
<div ng-if="root.originCountry == 'PAK'">
  <div ng-if="root.productType == 'Custom Football Jersey' || root.productType == 'Sublimated Football Jersey'">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="productTypeType">{{root.productType}} Type</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <select ng-model="root.productTypeType" ng-options="type for type in pakJerseyTypeList" bs-select required></select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ordered-container">
      <div ng-if="root.productTypeType">
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label" for="bodyColor">Body Color</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <select ng-model="root.bodyColor" ng-options="color for color in bodyColorList" bs-select required></select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="root.bodyColor == 'Other'"> 
          <div class="control-group no-count">
            <label class="control-label" for="bodyColorPmsCode">Body Color PMS Code</label class="control-label no-count">
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" ng-model="root.bodyColorPmsCode" name='bodyColorPmsCode' required>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe this is your solution : http://jsfiddle.net/dimitardanailov/nWCZv/

Comment: ^^^ It's an angular app, not jQuery.

Comment: Not sure how you have the 'nesting' set up, but if the state is nested:  `<div name="state" ng-if="usa && state"></div>`.  That may get a bit verbose, though.  Maybe post some example code?

Comment: "Unselect" the state when you select a new country.  ie, set it to null or empty or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the `ng-change` directive to your advantage; set one on a parent select box and implement its handler to clear the values of any child select box depending on it.

Here's a quick snippet illustrating how to achieve this:

```html
<select 
  ng-model="selectedCountry"
  ng-options="country for country in countries"
  ng-change="clearCity()">
</select>

<select 
  ng-model="selectedCity" 
  ng-if="isJapanSelected()" 
  ng-options="city for city in japanCities"
  ng-change="setCity(selectedCity)">
</select>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myModule', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.countries = ['Japan', 'Brasil', 'England'];
  $scope.selectedCountry = 'Brasil';
  $scope.selectedCity = '';
  $scope.japanCities = ['Tokyo', 'Yokohama', 'Osaka']
  $scope.isJapanSelected = function() {
    return $scope.selectedCountry == 'Japan';
  };
  $scope.getCity = function() {
    return $scope.selectedCity;
  };
  $scope.setCity = function(city) {
    $scope.selectedCity = city;
  };
  $scope.clearCity = function() {
    if (!$scope.isJapanSelected()) {
      $scope.selectedCity = '';
    }
  };
});
```

---

#### [Live demonstration on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vBJFOu3Y2Bnnvns2iUYh?p=preview)

Comment: So while this achieves the result I am looking for, it becomes unwieldy when I have to code it explicitly 50 times across the code base. Is there a way, perhaps with a directive that I could automatically do this?

Comment: well, you could group it all into a component (writing a directive that groups and encapsulates all dependent select boxes). i don't think i quite get what you mean?

Comment: Well what you just said is along the lines of what I meant. I don't want to have to indicate which fields are cleared when a field is change. If i could just say something like nested-if-model="country == 'Japan'" in the html and then that would act like an ng-if except it would automatically reset all models that are mentioned as children within the dom when the if statement is false.